# .closest with :contains selecting more than I'd like?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to highlight rows in a table in which some have a particular class assigned on $(document).ready.  Thought using .closest with a tr would grab just the corresponding row, but it's getting them all and I'm not sure why.

I've tried quite a few things but admittedly am just trying to follow along with tutorials/examples, I'm not a jquery guy and am far from comfortable with it, but here's where I'm at.

```
<table class="views-table cols-3" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="views-field views-field-created" scope="col">Upload Date</th>
<th class="views-field views-field-filename" scope="col">Name/File</th>
<th class="views-field views-field-path" scope="col">Download</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd views-row-first">
<td class="views-field views-field-created">October 09, 2017</td>
<td class="views-field views-field-filename"><a href="http://example.com/sample_0.pdf">sample_0.pdf</a></td>
<td class="views-field views-field-path" ><a href="/345" class="">Download</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="even views-row-last">
<td class="views-field views-field-created">January 16, 2019</td>
<td class="views-field views-field-filename"><a href="http://example.com2344234_0.pdf">2344234.pdf</a></td>
<td class="views-field views-field-path" ><a href="/445" class="1">Download</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    if ($("a").hasClass("1")) {
    $("a").closest('tr').css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
}); 
</script>
```

There's lots more rows in the full table, but for the sake of keeping it clean you can see there's just two table rows here, the latter of which has a link with class="1" in there.

I want just THOSE rows with that anchor class=1 within identified and to go blue here, but it ends up doing them all (or none when I break it even more.)

Do I need to run a loop here?  Is .closest not the right thing to use here?  I tried some parent references but had no luck.

Sorry if this is rudimentary, but I'm not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working is that you're calling `.closest` on `a`, which as a selector is not related to the condition you just tested.

In other words: `$('a').closest('tr')` is always the closest enclosing `<tr>` of **every** link.

You can simply use the following line instead, using [class selectors](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$('a.1').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

**Demo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <table class="views-table cols-3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="views-field views-field-created" scope="col">Upload Date</th>
        <th class="views-field views-field-filename" scope="col">Name/File</th>
        <th class="views-field views-field-path" scope="col">Download</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="odd views-row-first">
        <td class="views-field views-field-created">October 09, 2017</td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-filename"><a href="http://example.com/sample_0.pdf">sample_0.pdf</a></td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-path"><a href="/345" class="">Download</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="even views-row-last">
        <td class="views-field views-field-created">January 16, 2019</td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-filename"><a href="http://example.com2344234_0.pdf">2344234.pdf</a></td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-path"><a href="/445" class="1">Download</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('a.1').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'blue');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `jQuery(function($){ /*magic here*/ });` just a better DOM ready wrapper...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, I only changed the relevant part of the code.

Comment: Thanks Roko, I think I get what you're saying - my bad code just checked for a condition (which passed) then ran the highlight on every anchor.  Makes sense and this works great.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.each` in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $( "a" ).each(function() {
        if ($( this ).hasClass("1")) {
          $( this ).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'blue');
        }         
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="views-table cols-3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="views-field views-field-created" scope="col">Upload Date</th>
        <th class="views-field views-field-filename" scope="col">Name/File</th>
        <th class="views-field views-field-path" scope="col">Download</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="odd views-row-first">
        <td class="views-field views-field-created">October 09, 2017</td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-filename"><a href="http://example.com/sample_0.pdf">sample_0.pdf</a></td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-path"><a href="/345" class="">Download</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="even views-row-last">
        <td class="views-field views-field-created">January 16, 2019</td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-filename"><a href="http://example.com2344234_0.pdf">2344234.pdf</a></td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-path"><a href="/445" class="1">Download</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("1")) {
          $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'blue');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI even if you *can* (valid for IDs), HTML5 classes should not start with a number...

Comment: And there's no reason to use `.each()`. Use the right selector